# Trying to fix errors in my compiled jar

Tags: java

I compiled my jar and got the following:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Employees\firstname lastname.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EmployeeList.createEmployees(EmployeeList.java:127)
    at EmployeesWindow.<init>(EmployeesWindow.java:64)
    at ScheduleBuilder.<init>(ScheduleBuilder.java:17)
    at Start.main(Start.java:7)
```

My file path looks like this:

```
    File file = new File("Employees\\" + tempfirst + " " + templast + ".txt");
```

The folder is located here and contains a bunch employees text files:

```
    F:\Programming\Schedule Builder\Employees
```

How can I fix this so that I do not get this error?

Comment: change `Employees` to `F:\\Programming\\Schedule Builder\\Employees`

Comment: verify that the path of the file in your code is indeed the path you assume it is

Comment: Scary Wombat's suggestion would work, but I would recommend to put the path (if you want to hardcode it) in a properties file, that way you won't have to recompile each time you decide to change the path

Comment: what is tempfirst and templast

Comment: Yes, I agree that mine was not a good solution, just a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)

Comment: If you do not want to recompile or to store the path to that file in some sort of configuration, simply make sure your current directory is `F:\Programming\Schedule Builder\` (or whichever other location that contains the Employee directory) before you run your program.